# How is preg_match pattern for replace multiple <br /> with my conditions?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

How can i create preg_match pattern for replace multiply `<br />` in the strings that can contains lots of `<br />`.

And here is my condition for replaces.
1 if has only one or two `<br />` don't replace.

```
$str = "line 1<br />line 2<br /><br />line 3";
$result = "line 1<br />line 2<br /><br />line3";
```

2 if has more than two `<br />` replace them to double.

```
$str = "line 1<br />line 2<br /><br /><br />line3<br /><br />";
$result = "loading<br />checking<br /><br />line3<br /><br />";
```

*Consclusion* As my conditions that mean i will allow maximum two `<br />`.
Here is I've tried but it replaces all `<br />` to only one.

```
$detail = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['detail']));
$detail = preg_replace('#(<br */?>\s*)+#i', '<br />', $detail);
```

I've also search for this before but don't found any helps. That may I'm not experienced with preg_replace. So, i need your help and will truly appreciated . thank you.

Comment: Simple: Don't. use a dom engine and look for `<br>` which has more sibling `<br>` tags, then delete the siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code :

```
$detail = preg_replace('#(<br\s*\/?>\s*){3,}#i', '<br /><br />', $detail);
```

Will replace `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br />`... when they occur 3 times (or more) side by side. It also take care of extra spaces between them.

[**Example**](http://ideone.com/Jblu1Z)

Comment: @Marcus Sorry, I missed a little `*`. See my example.

Comment: Yeah @zessx it worked. but why when i insert to the database it still has newline `\n` in it.

Comment: Because `nl2br()` **add** a `<br>` tag before `\n`, it doesn't *replace* `\n`. After your treatment, you should use `str_replace( "\n", '', $detail)` to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

> If has more than two `<br />` replace them to double.

It might help you using substitution.

```
(<br\s?\/>){3,}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rS3aG4/16)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(<br\\s?\\/>){3,}/i";
$str = "...";
$subst = '<br \/><br \/>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Have a look at the demo.